# when updating a patricular record it is only updating first record

Tags: jquery, html, css, spring-mvc, bootstrap-4

When I am updating a particular record it is updating the first record in database   i cannot update the particular Record 
I used same techinuque for add it is working properly  i am using jquery 
to call the controller  from jsp there is anything wrong in the jquery 
for  calling the update please help me

**This is my backend code**

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "/campaign", method = RequestMethod.GET)

public ModelAndView campaign(CampaignModel cmp, HttpServletRequest request)

{
     UserDatabaseHelper udh=new UserDatabaseHelper();
    DealerUser dUser = udh.Getuser(request.getUserPrincipal().getName());

    int DealerID = dUser.getDealerId();

    //model.addAttribute("isUserClickedLogin", "true");
    DatabaseHelper dh = new DatabaseHelper();
    List<CampaignModel> cml = dh.GetDealerCampaignModels(DealerID);     
    ModelMap mm = new ModelMap();
    mm.addAttribute("campaingModel", cml);
    VehicleDatabaseHelper vdh=new VehicleDatabaseHelper();
    List<String> vms=vdh.GetVehicleMake();
    mm.addAttribute("vehicleMake",vms);
    List<VehicleModel> vm = vdh.GetVehiclMakeModel();
    mm.addAttribute("vehicleMakeModel", vm);


    ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("campaign", mm);
    return mv;
}
```

@RequestMapping(value = "/updatecampaign", method = RequestMethod.POST)

```
public String UpdateCampaign(CampaignModel cmp,HttpServletRequest request)

{   
    int result1=0;
    UserDatabaseHelper udh=new UserDatabaseHelper();
    DealerUser dUser = udh.Getuser(request.getUserPrincipal().getName());

    int DealerID = dUser.getDealerId();
    //model.addAttribute("isUserClickedLogin", "true");
    DatabaseHelper dh = new DatabaseHelper();
    result1=dh.UpdateCampaignModel(DealerID,cmp.getCampaignModelID(),cmp.getCampaignName(),cmp.getType(),cmp.getDealerLocation(),cmp.getYearFrom(),cmp.getYearTo(),cmp.getMake(),
            cmp.getModel().split("\\,")[0],cmp.getMiles(),cmp.getPriceFrom(),cmp.getPriceTo(),cmp.getPopularityIndex(),cmp.getAgeOfStock(),cmp.getRanking(),cmp.isEnabled());
      String strResult = "New Campaign Model could not be added. Please check values and try again";
     if(result1 != 0)
     {
         strResult = "New Campaign Model updated successfully";
     }
    List<CampaignModel> cml = dh.GetDealerCampaignModels(DealerID); 

    ModelMap mm = new ModelMap();
    mm.addAttribute("campaingModel", cml);
    mm.addAttribute("AddCampaignResult", strResult);
    VehicleDatabaseHelper vdh=new VehicleDatabaseHelper();
    List<String> vms=vdh.GetVehicleMake();
    mm.addAttribute("vehicleMake",vms);
    List<VehicleModel> vm = vdh.GetVehiclMakeModel();
    mm.addAttribute("vehicleMakeModel", vm);
    ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("campaign", mm);
    return "redirect:/campaign";    
    }
```

`

```html
this **This is my Jquery**
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js">
  $('button[type=submit]').click(
    function(e) {
      //alert("Button Clicked:"+e.currentTarget.id);


      //Prevent default submission of form
      e.preventDefault();

      //Remove all errors


      if (e.currentTarget.id == "btnaddcampaign") {
        $.post({


          url: 'addcampaign',
          data: $('form[name=addcmp]').serialize(),
          success: function(res) {

            if (res.validated) {
              //Set respons
              $('#resultContainer pre code').text(
                $(AddCampaignResult));
              $('#resultContainer').show();

            } else {
              //Set error messages
              $.each(res.errorMessages, function(key, value) {
                $('input[name=' + key + ']').after(
                  '<span class="error">' + value +
                  '</span>');
              });
            }

          }
        });
      }

      if (e.currentTarget.id == "btnupdatecampaign") {
        $.post({

          url: 'updatecampaign',
          data: $('form[name=updatecmp]').serialize(),
          success: function(res) {

            if (res.validated) {
              //Set respons
              $('#resultContainer pre code').text(
                $(UpdateCampaignResult));
              $('#resultContainer').show();

            } else {
              //Set error messages
              $.each(res.errorMessages, function(key, value) {
                $('input[name=' + key + ']').after(
                  '<span class="error">' + value +
                  '</span>');
              });
            }
          }
        });
      }

    });
</script>
this is my getting and updating a record
<div class="container">

  <c:forEach var="campaingmodel" items="${campaingModel}">

    <div class="jumbotron">
      <div class="container">
        <!-- 
       <div class="row"><label>Dealer ID</label> ${campaingmodel.getDealerID()}</div>
       <div class="row"><label>Campaign Model ID</label>${campaingmodel.getCampaignModelID()}</div>
        -->
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-1 col-xs-1">
                <span class="ubh-jumbotron-label">Type:</span>
              </div>
              <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-2 col-xs-3">
                <span class="ubh-jumbotron-value">${campaingmodel.getType()}</span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-1 col-xs-1">
                <span class="ubh-jumbotron-label">Make:</span>
              </div>
              <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-2 col-xs-3">
                <span class="ubh-jumbotron-value">${campaingmodel.getMake()}</span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-1 col-xs-1">
                <span class="ubh-jumbotron-label">Model:</span>
              </div>
              <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-2 col-xs-3">
                <span class="ubh-jumbotron-value">${campaingmodel.getModel()}</span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-1 col-xs-1">
                <span class="ubh-jumbotron-label">Year From:</span>
              </div>
              <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-2 col-xs-3">
                <span class="ubh-jumbotron-value">${campaingmodel.getYearFrom()}</span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-1 col-xs-1">
                <span class="ubh-jumbotron-label">Year To:</span>
              </div>
              <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-2 col-xs-3">
                <span class="ubh-jumbotron-value">${campaingmodel.getYearTo()}</span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-1 col-xs-1">
                <span class="ubh-jumbotron-label">Miles:</span>
              </div>
              <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-2 col-xs-3">
                <span class="ubh-jumbotron-value">${campaingmodel.getMiles()}</span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-1 col-xs-1">
                <span class="ubh-jumbotron-label">Price From:</span>
              </div>
              <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-2 col-xs-3">
                <span class="ubh-jumbotron-value">${campaingmodel.getPriceFrom()}</span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-1 col-xs-1">
                <span class="ubh-jumbotron-label">Price To:</span>
              </div>
              <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-2 col-xs-3">
                <span class="ubh-jumbotron-value">${campaingmodel.getPriceTo()}</span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-1 col-xs-1">
                <span class="ubh-jumbotron-label">Popularity:</span>
              </div>
              <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-2 col-xs-3">
                <span class="ubh-jumbotron-value">${campaingmodel.getPopularityIndex()}</span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-1 col-xs-1">
                <span class="ubh-jumbotron-label">Age Of Stock:</span>
              </div>
              <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-2 col-xs-3">
                <span class="ubh-jumbotron-value">${campaingmodel.getAgeOfStock()}</span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-1 col-xs-1">
                <span class="ubh-jumbotron-label">Ranking:</span>
              </div>
              <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-2 col-xs-3">
                <span class="ubh-jumbotron-value">${campaingmodel.getRanking()}</span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-1 col-xs-1">
                <span class="ubh-jumbotron-label">Version:</span>
              </div>
              <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-2 col-xs-3">
                <span class="ubh-jumbotron-value">${campaingmodel.getModelVersion()}</span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">

          <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-1 col-xs-1">
                <span class="ubh-jumbotron-label">Enabled:</span>
              </div>
              <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-2 col-xs-3">
                <span class="ubh-jumbotron-value">${campaingmodel.isEnabled()}</span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-1 col-xs-1">
                <span class="ubh-jumbotron-label">Location:</span>
              </div>
              <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-2 col-xs-3">
                <span class="ubh-jumbotron-value">${campaingmodel.getDealerLocation()}</span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-1 col-xs-1">
                <span class="ubh-jumbotron-label">Name:</span>
              </div>
              <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-2 col-xs-3">
                <span class="ubh-jumbotron-value">${campaingmodel.getCampaignName()}</span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>


        *This is Update Button*
        <div class="btn-group">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#${campaingmodel.getCampaignModelID()}">Update</button>
        </div>



        <div class="btn-group">
          <c:url value="/campaignlist/${campaingmodel.getCampaignModelID()}" var="url1"></c:url>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="location.href='${url1}'">Add Campaign</button>
        </div>

        <div class="btn-group">
          <c:url value="/setlist/${campaingmodel.getCampaignModelID()}" var="url"></c:url>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" onclick="location.href ='${url}'">Add Adset</button>
        </div>
        <div class="btn-group">
          <c:url value="/gettarget/${campaingmodel.getCampaignModelID()}" var="url2"></c:url>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="location.href='${url2}'">Add Target</button>
        </div>
        <div class="btn-group">
          <c:url value="/geteditform/${campaingmodel.getDealerID()}" var="url9"></c:url>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="location.href='${url9}'">Edit Campaign</button>
        </div>


      </div>
    </div>


    <!--  FOR UPDATE -->
    *Update Popup*
    <div class="modal fade" id="${campaingmodel.getCampaignModelID()}">


      <div class="modal-dialog">

        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Update Campaign</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">

            <form action="updatecampaign" method="POST" name="updatecmp" enctype="multipart/form-data">

              <div class="form-group row">
                <label class="control-label col-md-12" for="dealerID">Dealer
         ID:</label>
                <div class="col-md-12">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="DealerID" title="Dealer ID should not be empty" value="${campaingmodel.getDealerID() }" readonly>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="form-group row">
                <label class="control-label col-md-12" for="CampaignModelID">Campaign Model
         ID:</label>
                <div class="col-md-12">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="CampaignModelID" title="Dealer ID should not be empty" value="${campaingmodel.getCampaignModelID()}" readonly>
                </div>
              </div>


              <div class="form-group row">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                  <label class="control-label" for="yearFrom">Year
         From:</label>
                  <div class="col-xs-3">


                    <select class="target" name="YearFrom" value="${campaingmodel.getYearFrom()}">
                      <option value="2019" ${campaingmodel.getYearFrom()=='2019' ? 'selected="true"' : ''}>2019</option>
                      <option value="2018" ${campaingmodel.getYearFrom()=='2018' ? 'selected="true"' : ''}>2018</option>
                      <option value="2017" ${campaingmodel.getYearFrom()=='2017' ? 'selected="true"' : ''}>2017</option>
                      <option value="2016" ${campaingmodel.getYearFrom()=='2016' ? 'selected="true"' : ''}>2016</option>
                      <option value="2015" ${campaingmodel.getYearFrom()=='2015' ? 'selected="true"' : ''}>2015</option>
                      <option value="2014" ${campaingmodel.getYearFrom()=='2014' ? 'selected="true"' : ''}>2014</option>
                      <option value="2013" ${campaingmodel.getYearFrom()=='2013' ? 'selected="true"' : ''}>2013</option>
                      <option value="2012" ${campaingmodel.getYearFrom()=='2012' ? 'selected="true"' : ''}>2012</option>
                      <option value="2011" ${campaingmodel.getYearFrom()=='2011' ? 'selected="true"' : ''}>2011</option>
                      <option value="2010" ${campaingmodel.getYearFrom()=='2010' ? 'selected="true"' : ''}>2010</option>
                      <option value="2009" ${campaingmodel.getYearFrom()=='2009' ? 'selected="true"' : ''}>2009</option>
                      <option value="2008" ${campaingmodel.getYearFrom()=='2008' ? 'selected="true"' : ''}>2008</option>
                      <option value="2007" ${campaingmodel.getYearFrom()=='2007' ? 'selected="true"' : ''}>2007</option>
                      <option value="2006" ${campaingmodel.getYearFrom()=='2006' ? 'selected="true"' : ''}>2006</option>
                      <option value="2005" ${campaingmodel.getYearFrom()=='2005' ? 'selected="true"' : ''}>2005</option>
                    </select>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                  <label class="control-label" for="yearTo">YearTo:</label>
                  <div class="col-xs-3">


                    <select class="dropdown-toggle" name="YearTo" value="${campaingmodel.getYearTo()}">
                      <option value="2019" ${campaingmodel.getYearTo()=='2019' ? 'selected="true"' : ''}>2019</option>
                      <option value="2018" ${campaingmodel.getYearTo()=='2018' ? 'selected="true"' : ''}>2018</option>
                      <option value="2017" ${campaingmodel.getYearTo()=='2017' ? 'selected="true"' : ''}>2017</option>
                      <option value="2016" ${campaingmodel.getYearTo()=='2016' ? 'selected="true"' : ''}>2016</option>
                      <option value="2015" ${campaingmodel.getYearTo()=='2015' ? 'selected="true"' : ''}>2015</option>
                      <option value="2014" ${campaingmodel.getYearTo()=='2014' ? 'selected="true"' : ''}>2014</option>
                      <option value="2013" ${campaingmodel.getYearTo()=='2013' ? 'selected="true"' : ''}>2013</option>
                      <option value="2012" ${campaingmodel.getYearTo()=='2012' ? 'selected="true"' : ''}>2012</option>
                      <option value="2011" ${campaingmodel.getYearTo()=='2011' ? 'selected="true"' : ''}>2011</option>
                      <option value="2010" ${campaingmodel.getYearTo()=='2010' ? 'selected="true"' : ''}>2010</option>
                      <option value="2009" ${campaingmodel.getYearTo()=='2009' ? 'selected="true"' : ''}>2009</option>
                      <option value="2008" ${campaingmodel.getYearTo()=='2008' ? 'selected="true"' : ''}>2008</option>
                      <option value="2007" ${campaingmodel.getYearTo()=='2007' ? 'selected="true"' : ''}>2007</option>
                      <option value="2006" ${campaingmodel.getYearTo()=='2006' ? 'selected="true"' : ''}>2006</option>
                      <option value="2005" ${campaingmodel.getYearTo()=='2005' ? 'selected="true"' : ''}>2005</option>
                    </select>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                  <label class="control-label" for="miles">Miles:</label>
                  <div class="col-xs-3">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="Miles" value="${campaingmodel.getMiles()}">
                  </div>
                </div>

              </div>
              <div class="form-group row">
                <div class="col-md-4">

                  <label class="control-label" for="priceFrom">Price From:</label>

                  <div class="col-xs-3">


                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="PriceFrom" value="${campaingmodel.getPriceFrom()}">

                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">

                  <label class="control-label" for="priceTo">Price To:</label>

                  <div class="col-xs-3">

                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="PriceTo" value="${campaingmodel.getPriceTo()}">

                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">

                  <label class="control-label" for="popularityIndex">Popularity:</label>

                  <div class="col-xs-3">

                    <select class="target" name="PopularityIndex" value="${campaingmodel.getPopularityIndex()}">
                      <option value="1" ${campaingmodel.getRanking()=='1' ? 'selected="true"' : ''}>1</option>
                      <option value="2" ${campaingmodel.getRanking()=='2' ? 'selected="true"' : ''}>2</option>
                      <option value="3" ${campaingmodel.getRanking()=='3' ? 'selected="true"' : ''}>3</option>
                      <option value="4" ${campaingmodel.getRanking()=='4' ? 'selected="true"' : ''}>4</option>
                      <option value="5" ${campaingmodel.getRanking()=='5' ? 'selected="true"' : ''}>5</option>
                      <option value="6" ${campaingmodel.getRanking()=='6' ? 'selected="true"' : ''}>6</option>
                      <option value="7" ${campaingmodel.getRanking()=='7' ? 'selected="true"' : ''}>7</option>
                      <option value="8" ${campaingmodel.getRanking()=='8' ? 'selected="true"' : ''}>8</option>
                      <option value="9" ${campaingmodel.getRanking()=='9' ? 'selected="true"' : ''}>9</option>
                      <option value="10" ${campaingmodel.getRanking()=='10' ? 'selected="true"' : ''}>10</option>
                    </select>

                  </div>

                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group row">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                  <label class="control-label" for="ageOfStock">Age Of Stock:</label>
                  <div class="col-xs-3">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="AgeOfStock" title="Age Of Stock should not be empty" value="${campaingmodel.getAgeOfStock()}">
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                  <label class="control-label" for="ranking">Ranking:</label>
                  <div class="col-xs-3">
                    <select class="target" name="Ranking" value="${campaingmodel.getRanking()}">
                      <option value="1" ${campaingmodel.getPopularityIndex()=='1' ? 'selected="true"' : ''}>1</option>
                      <option value="2" ${campaingmodel.getPopularityIndex()=='2' ? 'selected="true"' : ''}>2</option>
                      <option value="3" ${campaingmodel.getPopularityIndex()=='3' ? 'selected="true"' : ''}>3</option>
                      <option value="4" ${campaingmodel.getPopularityIndex()=='4' ? 'selected="true"' : ''}>4</option>
                      <option value="5" ${campaingmodel.getPopularityIndex()=='5' ? 'selected="true"' : ''}>5</option>
                      <option value="6" ${campaingmodel.getPopularityIndex()=='6' ? 'selected="true"' : ''}>6</option>
                      <option value="7" ${campaingmodel.getPopularityIndex()=='7' ? 'selected="true"' : ''}>7</option>
                      <option value="8" ${campaingmodel.getPopularityIndex()=='8' ? 'selected="true"' : ''}>8</option>
                      <option value="9" ${campaingmodel.getPopularityIndex()=='9' ? 'selected="true"' : ''}>9</option>
                      <option value="10" ${campaingmodel.getPopularityIndex()=='10' ? 'selected="true"' : ''}>10</option>

                    </select>
                  </div>
                </div>


                <div class="col-md-4">
                  <label class="control-label" for="enabled">Enabled:</label>
                  <div class="col-xs-3">
                    <label class="switch">
        <c:choose>
        <c:when test="${campaingmodel.isEnabled()==true}">
        
         <input type="checkbox" id="ans" class="form-control" name="Enabled"
          title="Enabled should not be empty" value="${campaingmodel.isEnabled()}" checked="checked"/>
          </c:when>
          <c:otherwise>
          <input type="checkbox" id="ans" class="form-control" name="Enabled"
          title="Enabled should not be empty" value="${campaingmodel.isEnabled()}"/>
          </c:otherwise>
          </c:choose>
          <span class="slider round"></span>
          </label>



                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group row">
                <div class="col-md-3">

                  <label class="control-label" for="Type">Type:</label>


                  <div class="col-xs-3">
                    <select class="target" name="Type" value="${campaingmodel.getType()}" id="updtype">
                      <option value="ALL" ${campaingmodel.getType()=='ALL' ? 'selected="true"' : ''}>ALL</option>
                      <option value="NEW" ${campaingmodel.getType()=='NEW' ? 'selected="true"' : ''}>NEW</option>
                      <option value="OLD" ${campaingmodel.getType()=='OLD' ? 'selected="true"' : ''}>OLD</option>
                    </select>
                  </div>

                </div>


                <div class="col-md-4">

                  <label class="control-label" for="make">Make:</label>
                  <div class="col-xs-2">
                    <select id="upmakedropdown" name="Make">
                      <option value="ALL" selected="selected">ALL</option>
                      <c:forEach var="vehm" items="${vehicleMake}">

                        <option value="${vehm}" ${campaingmodel.getMake()==vehm? 'selected="true"' : ''}>${vehm}</option>


                      </c:forEach>
                    </select>
                  </div>
                </div>


                <div class="col-md-5">

                  <label class="control-label" for="model">Model:</label>

                  <div class="col-xs-4">
                    <select id="upmodeldropdown" name="Model">
                      <option value="ALL" selected="selected">ALL</option>
                      <c:forEach var="vehmm" items="${vehicleMakeModel}">
                        <option value="${vehmm.getMake()}.${vehmm.getModel()}" ${campaingmodel.getModel()==vehmm.getModel()? 'selected="true"' : ''}>${vehmm.getModel()}</option>
                      </c:forEach>
                    </select>
                  </div>

                </div>

              </div>


              <div class="form-group row">
                <label class="control-label col-md-12" for="dealerLocation">Dealer
         Location:</label>
                <div class="col-md-12">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="DealerLocation" title="Dealer Location should not be empty" value="${campaingmodel.getDealerLocation()}">
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="form-group row">
                <label class="control-label col-md-12" for="dealerLocation">Name:</label>
                <div class="col-md-12">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="CampaignName" title="Dealer Location should not be empty" value="${campaingmodel.getCampaignName()}">
                </div>
              </div>

            </form>

          </div>



          <div class="modal-footer">
            <div class="form-group">


              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" id="btnupdatecampaign" data-dismiss="modal">Submit</button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>

            </div>
          </div>





        </div>

      </div>
    </div>

  </c:forEach>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you show us your backend code ?

Comment: i have posted backend code